# Links with tables doesn't quite work

Tags: html

Could someone explain me why this works :

```
<a href="https://go.twitch.tv/ESL_SC2" target="blank">
  <h>click me</h>
</a>`
```

But this doesnt work :

```
<table>
<a href="https://go.twitch.tv/ESL_SC2" target="blank">
<th>click me</th>
</a>
</table>`
```

I have a table and want to make some cells links but i can't find a way around it.

Comment: The anchor goes inside of the table head. HTML has rules about what elements are valid within a parent tag. Here's a link http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#flow-content-0 there are probably better resources on the mdn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a>` elements aren't direct children of `<table>` elements.  Make the cell's *contents* clickable, not the cell's *structure*:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>
            <a href="https://go.twitch.tv/ESL_SC2" target="blank">click me</a>
        </th>
    </thead>
</table>
```

HTML elements have specific semantic meanings and permitted structures.  If you don't follow that structure, the HTML becomes invalid and its behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Put the link inside `<th></th>`. This should solve issue:

```
<th><a href="https://go.twitch.tv/ESL_SC2" target="blank">click me</a></th>
```

Comment: Oh great. Thanks that worked like a charm!. I did add in my main code. I just wrote it simple here to illustrate the problem